# How do I read response headers in a .NET 4.0 app running on IIS6?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0, asp.net-4.0, ihttpmodule

I am writing a custom IHttpModule implementor so I can log request/response information as required. However I've hit a stumbling block when attempting to read the response headers. HttpResponse.Headers is now only supported if you are running on IIS7 and in integrated pipeline mode. I need this module to be installed in web applications hosted under IIS6, so I need an alternative way to get this information.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score -1):

Why do you as the server need to read them?

I recall being able to write them as far back as IIS 5 in the Page.Load event handler.

Comment: I am writing a custom IHttpModule to enable us to log all request and response information to a database.